# Как считать результат по модели в зависимости от конкретного столба,содержащийся в матрице Х

Tags: python

Матрица Х содержит две колонки(Х1 и Х2),нужно вычислить Y от Х,построить график,
но как сделать так чтобы Y определялся не от всей матрицы Х,а конкретно от столбцов х1 или х2  в зависимости от графика,который нужно построить(Y от Х(1))или Y от Х(2))?Благодарю за подсказку

```
Y=W*X
sns.scatterlot(x='x1', y='y', data=data)
```

W-это вектор,вычисляется по формуле (X.T*X)^-1*Y
на вход поступает три колонки с данными,х1,х2,y
 нужно построить линейную регрессию,матрица Х содержит две колонки

Comment: для того, чтобы посчитать `Y(X)` - надо знать формулу ;) В вашем вопросе вообще мало что понятно...

Comment: ["Как задать хороший вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ["Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: `W` - это скаляр, вектор или матрица? Лучше всего привести в вопросе небольшие примеры входных и выходных данных